# How to reload dropdownlist

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to reload the dropdownlist.

If I now do a selection on the dropdownlist and I select other option then the previous values are also showing.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SelectedCategoriedFaqId").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Medicijnverstrekking/FAQ/SubCategorie/",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    Categorieid: this.value
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('SelectedCategoriedFaqId').val('').trigger('liszt:updated');
                    //alert("Data retrieval successfull");
                    var items = "";

                    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                        var opt = $("<option></option>")
                          .attr("value", val.Value)
                          .text(val.Text);
                        $('#FaqCategorie_Id').append(opt);
                    });

                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert("Something seems Wrong");
                }
            });

        });  
    });      
</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the following

```
$.each(data, function (i, val) {
                    var opt = $("<option></option>")
                      .attr("value", val.Value)
                      .text(val.Text);
                    $('#FaqCategorie_Id').append(opt);
                });
```

just write:

```
$('#FaqCategorie_Id').empty();
```

This will remove all the items from your dropdown and then the new ones you have gottent from you ajax request will be appended to your dropdown.

Comment: @savantKing you welcome dude. I suppose you tested it and it was that you wanted. Correct?

Comment: Yes, it worked. The dropdownlist will be refreshed now

Comment: Great, I was just wondering, because you haven't accepted my answer as a solution. Anyways, since it worked I am glad.

Comment: Hi Christos, you also have some experiance with asp.net MVC? Can I sent you something to ur email?

Comment: I have a few experience on ASP.NET MVC, but it would be better, if you post an answer here, in SO, because you will find more experienced users of SO in ASP.NET MVC. If you do so, please send me the link to have a look at it and see if I can help. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You should first remove all other options from the list before appending the ajax-retrieved options.  Assuming the first option is

```
<option value=""></option>
```

, you could:

```
success: function (data) {
    var ddl = $('SelectedCategoriedFaqId');
    ddl[0].options.length = 1;
    ddl.val('').trigger('liszt:updated');
    //alert("Data retrieval successfull");
    var items = "";

    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
        var opt = $("<option></option>")
            .attr("value", val.Value)
            .text(val.Text);
        ddl.append(opt);
});
```

HTH

Comment: HTH stands for Hope That Helps; since I was a few minutes after Christos, I have my suspicions that it didn't help as much as I had hoped it would :)